# Why matchers on alertname field configuration does not work?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alertManager yaml file that has `matchers` matching on `alertname`. However, the alert for `alertname` shows up in alertmanager but does not get paged to PagerDuty. My alerts based on `matchers` for `namespace` work in both alertManager and PagerDuty.

This is my config:

```
kube-prometheus-stack:
  alertmanager:
    alertmanagerSpec:
      replicas: 3
    config:
      global:
        resolve_timeout: 15m
      time_intervals:
        - name: business-hours
          time_intervals:
            - weekdays: ["monday:friday"]
              times:
                - start_time: "10:00"
                  end_time: "16:00"
              location: America/Denver
      route:
        group_by:
          - cluster
          - namespace
          - severity
          - alertname
        # A default receiver for all alerts
        receiver: default
        # The child route trees
        routes:
          - receiver: Team1
            active_time_intervals:
              - business-hours
            matchers:
              - alertname =~ "^Alert1"
          - receiver: Team1
            active_time_intervals:
              - business-hours
            matchers:
              - alertname =~ "Alert2"
          - receiver: Team1
            active_time_intervals:
              - business-hours
            matchers:
              - namespace =~ "Alert3"
```

The `matchers: - namespace` works but NOT `matchers: - alertname`. I have had a hard time finding fields for `matchers`. Is `alertname` a correct field name or should it be something else? Or is there something else entirely going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you need regex selectors here? Also, are you sure those selectors match full alertname?

Comment: They are regexp to match portions of strings in many alertnames. The names are not the full names but only snippets of what I want to alert on. So, I want all the alerts that match a portion of an alert name. (ex: I want all the KubeAPI alertnames to fire but have many alertnames with KubeAPI somewhere in the name. Therefore, I put `- alertname =~ "KubeAPI"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by incorrect interpretation of regex matches, and has nothing to do with label being matched.

Official documentations [states](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors):

> Regex matches are fully anchored. A match of env=~"foo" is treated as env=~"^foo$".

So in your case matcher used should be like this:

```
alertname =~ ".*KubeAPI.*"
```